# how do I get all items from a iteration combobox

Tags: javascript, rally

I used to use getItems get all items in a dropdownList.
http://developer.rallydev.com/developer/iteration-dropdown

but in the API 2.0 I can't find equivalent function to get all items from the iterations combobox.

Any idea?

another issue:

Using getRawValue returns only the iteration name, how could I get also the iteration start date and end date?

Comment: for instance all want I need is to get the next and previous iteration names, as my report should show some info from previous and next iteration as trend measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all items for the iteration combobox, you will need to get the store associated with the combobox.  The code below adds a listener to the store load and then returns all the records associated with that store.

Once you have a record, you can retrieve a value for a field using the get method and passing in the field name.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
        storeConfig: {
            listeners: {
                 load: function(store, records){
                    console.log(records);
                }
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            select: function(combobox) {
                console.log(combobox.getRecord().get("StartDate"));
                console.log(combobox.getRecord().get("EndDate"));
            }    
        }    
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
});
```